# Как избежать того, что асинхронная функция в качестве аргумента может привести к не отловленной ошибке

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

## Асинхронная функция в качестве аргумента может привести к не отловленной ошибке.

Переделываю старый код на `async-await` и где-то использовал уже асинхронные функции в качестве аргумента при вызове другой функции.

То есть просто игнорировал то, что они вернут промис, который в данном случае просто не нужен (не важно когда завершится функция и что будет в нагрузке промиса).

Если в таких асинхронных функциях-аргументах случится ошибка, то она выскочит на самый верх и убьёт процесс в ноде. Или в браузере просто будет в консоли.

### Вопрос:

Как избегать данных ситуаций средствами typescript, webstorm или чем-то ещё?

Нужно чтобы что-то мне во всём проекте подсветило данные места или не давало игнорировать возвращаемые промисы при использовании таких функций. Их очень легко принять за обычные и подложить себе мину. А так как уже много чего написал, то просто не реально уже найти все ситуации.

### Пример кода:

```js
async function myFunction(){
    console.log('ура, типа как синхронная');
    await new Promise(( _, reject )=>{
        setTimeout( ()=>{
            console.log('нате вам ошибочку! (см. в консоли браузера)');
            reject( Error('some-error') );
        }, 1500 );
    });
}

setTimeout( myFunction, 0 ); // <--- Тут мне нужна какая-то подсветка или запрет оставлять без catch
```

### Ищу что-то похожее на это:

Вот более-менее приемлемый вариант в вебшторме, но только для тела синхронных функций, а мне нужно для аргументов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы используете ESLint, может, это пригодится: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md

Comment: @vsemozhebuty не использую, но попробую, спасибо. Этот линтер умеет понимать что промис отбрасывается? Ведь ему нужно понять, что функция внутри не использует промис от аргумента.

Comment: К сожалению, я именно этим плагином не пользовался и не знаю TypeScript, так что не могу сказать.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, я исправил всего одно слово. Не нравится - откати, но однострочным не оставляй.

Comment: нет, в редакторе всё тоже было однострочным (когда нажимаешь править это видно) и повторюсь: правку можно отменить, а можно и отредактировать.

Comment: мы можем продолжить обсуждение особенностей оформления вопросов и в частности этого, но в чате. однако, обильное бессмысленное словоблудие истощит мои силы, что приведёт к тому, что я всё же не смогу отправить ответ на изначальный вопрос. продолжить? - да - нет

Comment: Тут проблема не в том, что результат выполнения асинхронной функции не обрабатывается никак, а в том, что при использовании `async\await` в случае ошибки выбрасывается exception, который надо ловить через `try\catch`.

Comment: ненене, это же всё можно на уровне IDE отлавливать а не в рантайме

Comment: Непонятно чем тут async функция отличается о любой другой которая кинет исключение в коллбеке setTimeout и это исключение точно так же вылетит вверх стека.

Comment: @AlexeyTen про них речь просто потому что ситуация такая сложилась именно с ними. Колбэчные так не использовал. И те что с колбэками, например в ноде, кладут ошибку в аргумент, а не выбрасывают.

Answer (score 0):

> Тут мне нужна какая-то подсветка или запрет оставлять без catch

- единственное что нашел - TSLint `no-floating-promises` (не проверял)

Выглядит как узкоспециализированная хотелка - расширяем задачу: "подсветка асинхронных функций".

- Искал плагин для VSCode - не нашел. :(

### TSLint `no-floating-promises`

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401561/4794368
- https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md

### а вообще

Как мне кажется, это должно решаться на уровне языка (типизированного). Если мы ждём на входе функцию (`function f1(f: Function): {}`) - она должна быть простой функцией а не промисом.

Так что для меня, эта ситуация выглядит как ?баг/кривизна TS.

песочница [там](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true#code/PQKhAIANmcAEAuBnAtAUwB4Ac0GMHoBOhA9oZOOAFDgQAWCCWSAXDAO6cB0CAnjklyEAllgQAbAIYA7AOZcys4ABMSuJMDozlAIxIkA1sEJpxaSUjQppJBGg18BQ0QQDMKAJxcGAW3EBiFGR0bDwCNGIyFFwSHx80aWQaEGAqKgAzAFdpfGESaXB0-QAKAEoWcAA3EmFlcABvcABfKgteHMLs3PzC-QBBJHbcMoqABVIfYUsAHmragD4G5rSqABUARgr6mkpwRzRwABIAMX7BjoBecGKuW8lCWVZwGV4AbQBdUvALxfHYqbQsxqynmO0oWRyCDyBXS62K6QqJzOQy%20jRau3AMHgwUwOHwRFIhDBhThRRIXyxgC4QQAMIJTwIAOEHAgD4QQBsIPTACwg1MA3CBMwCCIIAZEHAKGZgAkQemARhAaVQWqsAExbYkQ7ow0kVY5dKH5coNdG7LGIVC4sIEsiK0nInIU2CAXhBAKwggCEQUUSyn0tIY-ZHdWQ6Hfa63Lj3R4VF4fL4-KrAxUan3pWXwxFe5Wo5YY-U40L4iKExVxskDFGYm0Op2S10tKhAA)

```
function foo(): void { }
async function fooAsync(): Promise<void> { }


T1: {
    type $FooAsync = (...args: any[]) => Promise<void>
    function f1(f: $FooAsync) { }
    // @ts-expect-error
    f1(foo) // как и ожидалось - ошибка
}
T2: {
    function f1(f: Function): {}
    // @ts-expect-error
    f1(fooAsync) // нет ошибки

    type $Function = (...args: any[]) => void
    function f2(f: $Function) { }
    // @ts-expect-error
    f2(fooAsync) // нет ошибки
}
```

---

`// @ts-expect-error` - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments

---

### P.S.

Кто смелый - может зайти в песочницу по ссылке и прямо оттуда создать баг репорт. Ну или хотя бы proposal.

Comment: Думаю что проблема в том, что в стандартных библиотеках везде написано Function или ()=> any , и для этих ситуаций возвращаться может что угодно и функция-аргумент вообще любая проходит. Асинхронность функции в TS можно понять только по возвращаемому промису, что уже не верно. Вы подсказали верную мысль, что там, где я типизировал нормально, по крайней мере по промису отсеивается уже, это уже хорошая новость. Спасибо.

Comment: да, но. в блоке t1 если удалить `// @ts-expect-error` а потом навести мышку на подчёркнутую ошибку TS пишет: `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.(2345)` в блоке t2, я считаю, точно такая же ошибка (должна быть) только переменные местами поменялись ...

Comment: Точно. Вот совсем простой пример и выглядит точно как баг - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEp0AoUEMBOBzALhQwEoBeAPhQDdF4ATFU4uxlAb2BR5wLIDcwAL4hsAZwCeMNFDhJU2JWWIAFXIgC28cQFMAPGwbUOosJhxLmQkEA

Comment: Судя по этому ответу https://stackoverflow.com/a/59665086/11929476 баг-репорт делать бессмысленно. Они видимо намеренно это решили допустить в угоду комфорту, и просто закрыли глаза на угрозу ошибок.

Comment: Также есть вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400854/void-return-type-not-checked-in-typescript-prevent-floating-promises где говорят что даже с линтером отловить проблему не выйдет.

Comment: [ага, да -да :( и это у них норма](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECKDuZoFMAeAXZA7AJjAYgK5bDoCWA9ltAN7QC+AUIzsqGAE7LQBmxplaj2EAKAI6IAXHEQBKaQDcKZHI0gBPEr37kq0MAZHzoABQ4UAtmQjIAPEpUA+Wg2bCeIg2FnMA9P-9oAHloAH1oCkZ2KGgAQVpGaCT9aTAsdUTkgCNU9MYmaJgAIQTk6Bz9PKYWNnAubRJdIQoKEQAHTjALaSLjB1UeFpEsZHg4ox8gA) в дженериках TS нет проверки на `instaceof`

Comment: так что TS - это красивенький JSDoc поверх JS с малой долей сахара. и если это держать в голове - ...